# Update selectedindices based on textbox change

Tags: c#, listview, search, textbox

I've got a form that contains a listview which pulls in ticket info from a database. The database objects are all abstracted into a class library. There is a tabpage below the listview which displays various details of the tickets.

My problem is that I've implemented a search at the top of this form which isn't updating that tabpage, only the listview gets updated.  After typing in keywords the listview refreshes properly and any items that dont' contain the keywords are removed until the text from the search box is cleared.  But I can't get the tabpage to exhibit the same behavior.  The tabpage still always contains all tickets.

For example, if I were to search for something where only 1 ticket was returned in the listview and say that ticket was the 10th ticket on record; the tabpage would show me details for the very first ticket.  How can I get the tabpage to exhibit the same behavior as my listview after a search is made?

The tabpage currently gets filled with this function:

```
private void FillTicket()
    {
        try
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
            {
                CTicket thistkt = comp.Tickets[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]];
                dedit1.DocumentHTML = thistkt.LineItems.GetCombinedProblem();
                dedit2.DocumentHTML = thistkt.LineItems.GetCombinedResolution();
                lvAssignmentHistory.Items.Clear();

                            foreach (CInc_AssignmentHistory a in thistkt.AssignmentHistory)
                            {
                                 ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem();
                                itm.Text = a.pAsgn_Datetime.ToString();
                                itm.SubItems.Add(a.pAsgn_Group_fr);
                                itm.SubItems.Add(a.pAsgn_from);
                                itm.SubItems.Add(a.pAsgn_Group_to);
                                itm.SubItems.Add(a.pAsgn_to);
                                itm.SubItems.Add(a.pChanged_By);
                                lvAssignmentHistory.Items.Add(itm);
                }
```

when this is called:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        //FillTicket();

        if (txtBox_TicketSearch.Text != "") 
        {
            FillTicketNothing();
        }
        else
        {
            FillTicket();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you only update the tab page if the user **selects** different items in your `ListView`.
If your `listView1_SelectedIndexChanged` method is only a handler for the `ListView.SelectedIndexChanged` event, it is only called when the **selection** in `listView1` changes, not when it's content is changed (without changing selection).

So you should call `FillTicket` when you changed the content of `listView1.Items` after your search.

Also, your `FillTicket` method only updates the tabpage if there are selected items in your ListView:

```
if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
```

I don't know if there is an `else`-branch for that if. If not, there will nothing change on your tab page if no items were selected. You may want to use `listView1.Items.Count`.